# Invalid Parameter 'variant' when attempting to change from fixed to dynamic disc in Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot is my attempted command to create a copy of the current disc but as a dynamic version before removing the original, as per this link https://www.howtogeek.com/312456/how-to-convert-between-fixed-and-dynamic-disks-in-virtualbox/

The second screenshot shows the path to the current version of the disc to show that I typed the path correctly (I think)

However, as you can see I am getting an error suggesting variant isn't a valid parameter? I'm sure it is something small that I am missing, but hopefully someone with a better trained eye can catch it!

Answer (score 0):

But I´ve just found the problem

Try

VboxManage clonemedium  disk  "inputfile.vdi" "outputfile.vdi" -variant Standard

I was missing the "disk" word and the option is "-variant" instead of "--variant"